# Calling custom R Script using rJava

Tags: java, r, rjava

I am trying to call a custom R script through my java application. This application makes use of rJava.

This is the custom script in R:

```
foo <- function(str) {
    return(str);
}
```

and this is my java class:

```
package pkg;

import org.rosuda.JRI.*;

public class Temp {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Start Rengine.
        Rengine r = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);

        if (!r.waitForR()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot load R");
            return;
        }

        r.eval("source(\'foo.R\')");
        r.eval("a = foo(\"hi\")");

        REXP a = r.eval("a");

        System.out.println(a.toString());

    }
}
```

Running this code gives me a Null pointer exception error for the REXP variable 'a'. Which indicates that the custom r script is not being sourced properly?

What do I need to resolve this issue? Must the custom R script be stored in a specific location? Currently, it is placed in the pkg package along with the java class.

I have seen multiple questions on this topic but I have not been able to find an appropriate solution to my problem. I cannot make use of RServe as the application will be used in machines that may not have a network connection or lack R libraries to run a local server.

Comment: I don't know R, but isn't it customary for programming languages to pair an open paren with a closed one? Like in `"source(\'foo.R\')"` rather than just `"source(\'foo.R\'"`?

Comment: good catch, that was a typo. still produces the same error unfortunately .

Comment: I also assume you are checking in your code if [null if something wnet \[sic\] wrong](http://rforge.net/org/docs/org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.html#eval(java.lang.String)) when eval-ing the loading of your source, aren't you? Because, you surely know that a non detected error at start may cascade in others later on the execution course.

Comment: Does setting [DEBUG>0](http://rforge.net/org/docs/org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.html#DEBUG) helps?

Comment: thanks that was helpful. its indicating an error when calling source('foo.R') but doesn't give a description on the kind of error it is.

Comment: The docos say the larger the debug value, the more details. Maybe setting it to 4 or 5 will get you to the 'INFO' level of logging?

Comment: i went up to 1mil but no change on verbosity. I wasn't able to find the documentation until now. You've pointed me in the right direction, thanks

Comment: If you are not sure whether R loads your script, you can call rEngine.eval("getwd()"). Does this print the right location to the console? I remember that I had similar problems and I ended up putting the full path to the R Engine. Once the script is loaded, you fetch the result in the line `result = r.eval("a = foo(\"hi\")");` and then `result.toString()`. No need to call `r.eval("a")` separately.